# How to insert a short code into Contact Form 7 in Wordpress that will call a function once the submit button is pressed

Tags: shortcode

How (or where) do I insert a short code that will call a function (written in a plugin called 'code snippets') when the submit button is pressed. I am trying to get the submit button to send data to an external database instead of sending mail. I have the actual function written already but no matter where  I place the short code nothing happens when the submit button is pressed. The external database lives on the same IP address as the wp database. I have been struggling with this short code for a bit of time now so thought  I would pose the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by changing the action of the particular form and then use the function to store the data in the database into a new file.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url($url)
{
    global $post;
    $id_to_change = 1;
    if($post->ID === $id_to_change)
        return 'wheretopost.asp';
    else
        return $url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but  i am unsure where to put this - I am a experienced programmer but not in wordpress which i find exceedingly confusing especially when it comes to where to place code. Where would this go